# Limit of a function at $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $$ f(x) = \frac{e^{2\pi x}}{(1 - e^{2 \pi x})^2} - \frac{1}{(2\pi x)^2}$$ Can someone provide a formula for

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{d^k f(x)}{dx^k}$$ or at least for $\frac{d^k f(x)}{dx^k}$ ? Everything I've tried so far was L'Hospital but after few derivatives I've gave up and used Wolfram Alpha to test my results ... I've also been thinking about using the Cauchy Integral formula since $f(z)$ is holomorphic (I think) on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ i\cdot n| n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and can be continued analytically to $\mathbb{C}$ using Riemann theorem on removable singularities ... Can someone help?

Comment: Have a look at the generating function for Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a particular contour integral? The derivatives will involve bernoulli numbers and are not fun.

Comment: No I am simply interested in $\lim_{x \to 0} f^{(k)}(x)$ and I do not know how  to obtain it... :(

Comment: Sir, can you, please provide an explicit relation with Bernoulli numbers then? :D

Comment: how about a Taylor series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bernoulli numbers are usually defined through
$$ \frac{z}{e^z-1} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_n}{n!} z^n \tag{1}$$
Now we substitute $z\mapsto 2\pi z$, leading to:
$$ \frac{2\pi}{e^{2\pi z}-1}=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{B_n(2\pi)^n}{n!} z^{n-1} \tag{2} $$
then differentiate both sides with respect to $z$, leading to:
$$ -\frac{4\pi^2 e^{2\pi z}}{(e^{2\pi z}-1)^2}=-\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{B_n(2\pi)^n (n-1)}{n!} z^{n-2} \tag{3}$$
By rearranging it follows that:
$$ \frac{e^{2\pi z}}{(e^{2\pi z}-1)^2}-\frac{1}{4\pi^2 z^2}=-\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{B_{m+2}(2\pi)^{m}}{(m+2)m!} z^{m} \tag{4}$$
and:
$$ \frac{d^m}{dz^m}\left.\left(\frac{e^{2\pi z}}{(e^{2\pi z}-1)^2}-\frac{1}{4\pi^2 z^2}\right)\right|_{z=0} = \color{red}{-\frac{B_{m+2}(2\pi)^m}{(m+2)}}.\tag{5}$$